# Suggested way to use camel route for large data update

Tags: sql, apache-camel, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

In current project there is a requirement of implementing a batch process that needs to be executed once every day. This batch job needs to read data from multiple tables from one database do some manipulation in data and place it in another database. Data size is huge, its millions of record need to be manipulated.
Camel routing using blueprint in JBOSS Fuse is suggested way to execute this process.
Being new to camel I need suggestions, shall it be good idea to put queries as separate route or should I be handling it through a single route with all query part of a bean class marking that in 'to' clause of a route
Multi-threading can also be used to improve performance, and the deployment will be done on multiple servers.